# Error : "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" though have been used ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ssl, tls1.2

I'm having a bug when I bring up the client's Win Server 2012 R2. The error is after calling a request, searching Google and trying many methods on the internet but still can't do anything. I checked with Wireshark and it shows active TLS12. Even though it's just a modified function. Other functions are still running smoothly. Please help me take a look, thank you very much everyone.
The project uses Entity framework 4.5.

```
{Message: "An error has occurred.",ExceptionMessage: "An error occurred while sending the request.",…}
ExceptionMessage: "An error occurred while sending the request."
ExceptionType: "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException"
InnerException: {Message: "An error has occurred.",…}
ExceptionMessage:"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
ExceptionType: "System.Net.WebException"
Message: "An error has occurred."
StackTrace: " at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)"
Message: "An error has occurred."
StackTrace: " at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at LV.Service.NHDT.BankTransferordersController.<SendRequestLogout>d__6.MoveNext()"`
```

With my code:

```cs
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
string partner = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Partner"];

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
//code call request
```

I have tried the methods like the previous posts but it doesn't work, I want to understand what the problem is and fix it.

Comment: Why are you using .NET 4.5 and Server 2012R2 when they are both way out of support now? Have you followed the instructions and installed all the latest updates and made the registry changes to enable TLS1.2 https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392

Comment: yes i fixed no image and convert to text, sorry for this inconvenience.